# Why javascript Cannot read property width of textureImage

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to render image texture dynamically but in console it displays Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined. few suggest to make needsUpdate = true to false. When I am doing so some unpleasing black patch is appearing .But I need it true. how can i do so?
Actual code is very big i am pointing where problem occurs..

```
var g = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100);
var tx =THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imgUrl,undefined,callback,callbackError);
var m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
 map:tx
});
m.map.needsUpdate = true;  //1
tx.needsUpdate = true;  //2
////if 1 and 2 is commented then its ok but rendering is not good
var b = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(g,[
  m
 ,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframeLinewidth:3,color:0x222222,wireframe:true})
]);
```

Comment: nowhere in this code is a property `width` even referenced ... usually the error would show an associated file/line number

Comment: if you see @kaigorodov's thing then you will understand what i wanted. give a little time to understand than simply reading.

Comment: pretty condescending remark considering you only posted code because I said you should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a situation when renderer tries to use you texture before it is loaded. When you do

```
var tx =THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imgUrl,undefined,callback,callbackError);
```

the texture is returned but image itself is not yet loaded. So renderer tries to take width and height to find out is your texture power of 2 and throws an error in this moment.

You may try to wrap creation of your object and placing it to the scene into the callback function and pass it as the third parameter to the `loadTexture` method. Something like that:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
var tx =THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imgUrl, undefined, function(texture){
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
        map: texture
    });
    var b = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(
        geometry,
        [
            material,
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframeLinewidth:3,color:0x222222,wireframe:true})
        ]
    );
}, callbackError);
```

Comment: I think you should be using TextureLoader as loadTexture being deprecated